# Storing four thousand elements in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Does it make sense to store 4 thousand IPs in a php array (would it 
be a bad practice if I use opcache?)

The php file is around 50kb in size
And I think even my small ram server (512mb) wouldn't have a problem with
an array that small. I'll be using opcache so I think that would help too.

Is it a bad practice? Or I should store them in a database? I want
to fetch them randomly so I don't see why I should need to store them
in the database.

Comment: 4,000 elements isn't a small array - [How big are PHP arrays really](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)

Comment: And every time you want to add a new IP Address, that's a change to your code, which becomes a burden if you're using any form of version control (and if you're not, then you should be)

Comment: I was judging by the array size. If the file size is 50kb I don't think the array would take up more than 100kb in ram. Or is it?

Comment: I don't want to add more those will probably never change.

Comment: The article I linked to tells you exactly how to calculate the overheads for 32-bit or 64-bit PHP (PHP5, not PHP7 where the storage overheads are different)

Comment: "56 bytes per element" wouldn't be a problem for 4k array elements I judge....

Comment: 76 bytes per element, plus the size of the stored value itself (you don't indicate whether you're storing as a string, or what.... but that would be 16 bytes for the string, plus 28 for the zval for that string..... that's 120 bytes per entry, times 4000.... now your array is 480k, allow for the fact that each concurrent request has its own copy of that array

Comment: Just one warning: don't use ``array_key_exists`` on such arrays, it really affects the speed.

Comment: I said I'm storing IPs so 12byte max for their value....

Comment: I'm just doing a random select of the array. I don't think that would be an intensive process for the cpu. Not compared to querying mysql at least.Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I guess it could be OK. If you *care*, measure. note: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php